# Obtener el id de mi ArrayList y ponerlo en un TexView

Tags: java, android, array

Quisiera obtener el id del elemento seleccionado en un Spinner

```
 ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(c,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,spacecrafts);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);


        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(c,spacecrafts.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Aqui es donde se asigna el valor a spacecraft

```
private int parseData()
{
    try {
        JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(jsonData);
        JSONObject jo=null;

        spacecrafts.clear();
        curso s=null;

        for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++)
        {
            jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);

            int id=jo.getInt("id");
            String name=jo.getString("name");

            s=new curso();
            s.setId(id);
            s.setName(name);

            spaceid.add(Integer.toString(id));
            spacecrafts.add(name);


        }

        return 1;

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dentro de `onItemSelected()`  puedes obtenerlo a partir de la posicion (position), ya que `spacecrafts` es un Array de objetos `curso`, considerando obviamemte que el objeto tiene un getter para obtener el Id:

```
spacecrafts.get(position).getId()
```

Por ejemplo, usando el Toast lo ppdrías mostrar:

```
Toast.makeText(c,"El id es " + spacecrafts.get(position).getId(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

---

Para poner el valor en un `TextView`

```
textView.setText(spacecrafts.get(position).getId());
```

Comment: y para ponerlo en un TexView como haria ?

Comment: @RodolfoGav define una variable para el TextView y mediante el mètodo setText() agregas el valor, ve la respuesta, si tienes un TextView agrega tu codigo y con gusto te senalo donde agregarlo, saludos.

Comment: en la Activity esta declarada asi:


`tid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tid)`


lo que quiero hacer es mandar el id seleccionado(osea con el position) desde una clase a la actividad y se pueda ver en un TextView

Comment: Lo deseas realizar en la misma Actitividad  ? tid.setText(spacecrafts.get(position).getId()); esto dentro de onItemSelected()

Comment: Da el siguiente error

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.nfis.prueba3, PID: 28927
                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: Es lo que te pregunto wl TextView esta en la misma clase del código dr tu pregunta? Al parecer no encuentra la referencia del TextView

Comment: Pues mi TextView esta declarado en mi:

 `public class Pasar extends AppCompatActivity {
    
     public TextView tid;
 ...............
 @onCreate{

        tid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tid);
 ...............
  `
En mi class PasarDatos Todo lo que esta arriba

Comment: Ok únicamente asegura que dentro del layout  .xml que se carga por medio de setContentView() se encuentre el TextView con Id: tid

Comment: `<TextView
            android:text="aa"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tid" />`

Comment: Agrega tu onCreate() me parece que no estas cargando tu layout! :0

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_pasar);

Comment: Dentro de activity_pasar se encuentra el TextView con id : tid?

Comment: no, crei que solo se ponia en el content_pasar

Comment: No funciona te mando mi proyecto haber si lo chekeas
[https://mega.nz/#!NIkh0D6a!sm04Dn9qe8NRMBmz6GNM5eRBsJBPCKY_duL4oP5VAP8]

Comment: hey man, ya encontre el error. Se te agradece man

Comment: Que bien Rodolfo, el último error es asegurar que exista el elemento TexView en el layout.